# jQuery div hover function not working in Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, hover, firefox3.5, background-position

http://cambridgeuplighting.com/testimonials

This code works in Safari, IE7, and IE8, but not in FF 3.5.7.  The code changes the background of the little background icon when you hover over a div.

```
jQuery(function( $ ){
 $('.oneThird').hover(function(){
  $(this).find('span.icon').css( {'background-position-y': '-60px'} );
 }, function(){
  $(this).find('span.icon').css( {'background-position-y': '0px'} );
 });
});
```

Can someone help?  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

background-position-y is not supported by firefox as you can see [here](http://www.aptana.com/reference/html/api/CSS.field.background-position-y.html).  use `background-position: 0 -60px;` instead (thus including the x and y positions instructions).